# Is opt-in now required for iOS app using Fabric/Crashlytics/Flurry due to GDPR?

Tags: software, gdpr

It's been a while since I last pushed out an app to the iOS store, and since then the new EU requirements for data protection General Data Protection Regulation Compliance, GDPR, came into force. Most of what I can find in a Google search seems to come from entities pushing a commercial solution for GDPR in apps, and other snippets that don't look applicable or are just an over-the-top compliance advice.

I am a one person LLC entity, about to push out a free app, mostly to demonstrate my Swift coding ability. I plan to use both Fabric/Crashlytics and Flurry to monitor crash history and also analytics. Does anyone who actually has an iOS app recently submitted to the store know if I need to provide an opt-in screen on first run before enabling Crashlytics and Flurry? My inclination right now is to prevent the app being available in the EU to avoid legal issues.
Thanks

Comment: It would kind of depend on the app and what info you collecting. Fabric and Crashlytics are nice, but depending on the situation it could be collecting different things.

Comment: An opt-in is a way to gather consent for processing data, which is kind of the last resort legal basis for processing (see [Art. 6](https://www.privacy-regulation.eu/en/article-6-lawfulness-of-processing-GDPR.htm)). Depending on what data you're talking about, you may be able to find a different legal basis.